# Pass variable to closure on event trigger

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, closures

I have a loop where I define a closure for an event:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    obj.onload = function(e) {
        me.myFunction(e, i);
    };
}
```

I need to pass that counter variable to the function that is called when the `load` event is triggered. I always get the same value being passed.

How can I pass the right counter value to the function?

Comment: did you try passing i to the function callback?

Answer (score 5):

The usual way to solve this is with a builder function, so that the handler closes over something that doesn't change:

```
function buildHandler(index) {
    return function(e) {
        me.myFunction(e, index);
    };
}
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    obj.onload = buildHandler(i);
}
```

You *can* do that with an immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE), but in *theory* it creates and throws away a function on every loop (I expect most JavaScript engines these days optimize that) and I, at least, think it's a lot harder to read:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    obj.onload = (function(index) {
        return function(e) {
            me.myFunction(e, index);
        };
    })(i);
}
```

There's an ES5 feature, `Function#bind`, that you can use if you want to use `me.myFunction` directly, but you'd have to change the order in which you were expecting the arguments (`index` first, *then* the event):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    obj.onload = me.myFunction.bind(me, i);
}
```

`bind` creates a function that, when called, calls the original function with `this` set to the first argument (so, `me` above), then any further arguments you give it, and then any arguments that were used when calling the function. (That's why the order `myFunction` was expecting them had to change to `index, e` rather than `e, i`.)

On older browsers, you need a shim for `Function#bind`.

Comment: Just so I can know, if I would to use `Ext.Function.bind()` from the ExtJS library, how would that code look like? http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Function-method-bind

Comment: @DanielRibeiro: Wow, those docs are unclear, but I think it would be `obj.onload = Ext.Function.bind(me.myFunction, me, [i], true);` and `myFunction` should expect to get the event object first, then the index. But, um, you'd have to double-check that.

Comment: @DanielRibeiro: Strange. I'm afraid I can't help, the most recent version of Ext on Google's ajax libs is 3.0.x and doesn't have that function.

Comment: Not a problem at all. The first solution solves the issue and is actually pretty. Thanks!